Why does Kabbalah use the term "olamot" conjugated in the feminine when the Tanakh conjugates it as "olamim" in the masculine?
I'm curious why "olam" would be conjugated in the feminine throughout Kabbalah (as in the "arba'ah olamot") when as far as I know it is a masculine noun and is conjugated with the "olamim" ending in Tanakh. A brief search suggests that olamim refers to worlds (space) and olamot refers to eternities (time), but I haven't found a source to explain or confirm this idea.

https://hebrew-academy.org.il/2014/10/07/%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA/

Worth noting that even when using the plural olamot the word is still definitely masculine, not feminine. (If it was feminine we would have ארבע עולמות, rather than ארבעה עולמות.)

Welcome to MiYodeya Emunah and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

There are several words that are treated as both masculine and feminine within Tanach (such as Shabbos - see Kesubos 5a Tosafos sv "shema"). In addition grammar may have shifted between Biblical and Rabbinic Hebrew (such as the word "Ohel", which Biblically is masculine, but the mesechta is called Ohalos)

A similar case appears in the Gemara in Chullin 137b:

כי סליק איסי בר היני אשכחיה לר' יוחנן דקא מתני ליה לבריה רחלים אמר ליה אתנייה רחלות א"ל כדכתיב (בראשית לב, טו) רחלים מאתים אמר ליה לשון תורה לעצמה לשון חכמים לעצמן
§ When Isi bar Hini ascended from Babylonia to Eretz Yisrael, Rabbi Yoḥanan found him teaching the mishna to his son. Isi taught that the obligation of the first sheared wool applies only in the case of sheep [reḥelim], the masculine plural form of raḥel, meaning a sheep. Rabbi Yoḥanan said to Isi: You should teach him using the term reḥelot, the feminine plural form. Isi said to him in reply: I teach the mishna in accordance with that which is written: “Two hundred reḥelim” (Genesis 32:15). Rabbi Yoḥanan said to Isi: The language of the Torah is distinct and the language of the Sages is distinct, i.e., these are like two separate languages, and the Sages do not always use the same forms that appear in the Bible. In this case, they use reḥelot rather than reḥelim.

The commentary Ben Yehoyada says that the form that ends with ת implies more connection between the individuals than the one that doesn't (see there for why that is important in the Rabbinic context.) Perhaps the Kabbalists are trying to emphasize the connectedness of the worlds, which is a foundational principle of Chazal's worldview (see Ramchal's introduction to Aggadta.)
The word Olamim in the Bible refers to periods of time. An olam is a long time (sometimes 50 years), and olamim is many periods of time, often eternity (see here). Olamot in the Rabbinic literature refers to spiritual realms.
